# Creating dynamic tabpanels

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny, lapply, do.call

A "tabpanel" is created based on the read data, and a "tabpanel" is created using the numericInput value in the "tabpanel". However, in the current code, changing the numericInput to create the "tabpanel" will reset other inputs (such as selectInput) contained in the "tabpanel. Is there a solution?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)

server <- 
  shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    items <-  reactive(iris$Species %>% unique())

    observeEvent(input$action_1,{
      lapply(1:length(items()), function(i){
        assign(paste0("num_tabpanel_", i), 
               reactiveVal(3), 
               env=.GlobalEnv)
      })
    })

    observeEvent(input$action_1,{
      lapply(1:length(items()), function(i){
        observeEvent(input[[paste0("action_make_tab_", i)]],{
          get(paste0("num_tabpanel_", i))(input[[paste0("num_tabpanel_", i)]])
        })
      })
    })

    observeEvent(input$action_1,{
      output$ui_tag <- renderUI({
        tagList(
          do.call(tabsetPanel, lapply(1:length(items()), function(i){
            tabPanel(
              title = items()[i], #  %>% as.character()
              tags$br(),
              selectInput(paste0("select_", i),
                          label = "select",
                          choices = list("one" = 1, "two" = 2, "three" = 3),
                          selected = 1),
              numericInput(paste0("num_tabpanel_", i),
                           label = "tabpanel_number",
                           value = get(paste0("num_tabpanel_", i))(),
                           min = 1),
              actionButton(inputId = paste0("action_make_tab_", i),
                           label = "make_tabpanel_2"),
              tags$br(),tags$br(),
              do.call(tabsetPanel, lapply(1:get(paste0("num_tabpanel_", i))(), function(j){
                tabPanel(
                  title = j,
                  selectInput(paste0("select_tab_", i),
                              label = "select",
                              choices = list("one" = 1, "two" = 2, "three" = 3),
                              selected = 1),
                )
              }))
            )
          }))
        )
      })
    })
  })

ui <- 
  shinyUI(
    dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(title = "dynamic_tabpanel"),
      dashboardSidebar(),
      dashboardBody(
        actionButton(inputId = "action_1",
                     label = "make_tabpanel_1"),
        uiOutput("ui_tag")
      ),
    )
  )

options(shiny.reactlog = TRUE)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Welcome! Thank you for providing a reproducible example. However, the code is very hard to follow. Could you work more on making the example _minimal_, that is, isolating the issue with the minimal amount of code necessary to reproduce it?

Comment: It's difficult to follow exactly what your code does but judging from your question I would recommend looking into conditionalpanel() (from Shiny). It is the same as tabPanel but it is only rendered when you meet a certain condition. You can link that to your numericInput